# Merge Search Results From Multiple Field Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question about [live searching a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450186/search-html-table-and-display-results-without-refresh) but I have multiple fields like text and select dropdown fields. I wrote a js code based on the answer I got from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450186/search-html-table-and-display-results-without-refresh):

```
$("#deviceName").keyup(function(){
    var deviceNameFilter = $(this).val();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(deviceNameFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
$("#broadcastProg").change(function(){
    var broadcastProgFilter = $("#broadcastProg option:selected").text();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(broadcastProgFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
$("#store").change(function(){
    var storeFilter = $("#store option:selected").text();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(storeFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
$("#deviceModel").change(function(){
    var deviceModelFilter = $("#deviceModel option:selected").text();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(deviceModelFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
$("#deviceStatus").change(function(){
    var deviceStatusFilter = $("#deviceStatus option:selected").text();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(deviceStatusFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
$("#logOutputLog").keyup(function(){
    var logOutputLogFilter = $(this).val();
    $("#device-list_table tbody tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(logOutputLogFilter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

For example, I input keywords on `deviceName` field, the table updates and displays the results, but when I select an option from `broadcastProg` dropdown field, it also displays the results but only results from the selected option without considering `deviceName` field's results. So it should be that, say when I input "iPhone" perhaps in `deviceName` text field and choose "Schedule 1" in `broadcastProg` dropdown field, then the table should display the rows with "iPhone" under Device Name column and "Schedule 1" under Broadcasted Program column. How do I merge the results then?

Also, `deviceName` field should only search Device Name column, excluding other columns. In my case, it searches all the columns.

Hope someone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your `deviceName` field is the first column then you can write like this to search in this column only

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#deviceName").keyup(function(){
    var deviceNameFilter = $(this).val();
    $("#device-list_table td:first-child ").each(function(){
       if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(deviceNameFilter, "i")) < 0) {
         $(this).parent().hide();
       }else {
         $(this).parent().show();
       }
  });
});
```

And your `broadcastProg` is in second column then you can give `td:nth-child(2)` instead of `td:first-child`

For merging you need to implement some logic..for eg: You are showing element in the else part right? there you can give an if condition like this

```
if( $("#broadcastProg option:selected").text()== ""){
        $(this).parent().show();
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but what do you mean to avoid merging? I wanted to merge the results, not to avoid it.

Comment: alright. thanks. so do I put more if condition statements in my else part for the rest of my text fields and dropdown fields?